# Why is 2…f6 a blunder in the Center Game?

Tags: opening, analysis, beginner, center

```
[FEN "rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR"]
[Title "Center Game"]
[StartFlipped "1"]

1. e4 e5 2. d4 f6??
```

Stockfish says that **2…f6** was a blunder and recommends **2…exd4** instead.

I understand why **2…exd4** is the best move for Black, and I have seen people explain why **2…d6** and **2…Nc6** are not as good. However, none of the resources I found mentions **2…f6**.

I know that **2…f6** blocks the f6 square which could be used to develop the knight. However, I assume that the knight can be developed to e7 later. Also, **2…f6** might have an advantage over **2…d6**, since, if White captures the pawn on e5, Black can then capture back toward the center, which as I know is generally a good thing.

Comment: "Never play f6!" -- GM Ben Finegold

Comment: So many players on lichess fall into this, it's such a pleasure to punish it :-)))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason is that after 3. dxe5 fxe5 4. Qh5+ you are in a lot of trouble and already lost.

```
[fen ""]

1. e4 e5 2. d4 f6 3. dxe5 fxe5 4. Qh5+ Ke7 (4...g6 5. Qxe5+ Kf7 6. Bc4+) 5. Qxe5+ Kf7 6. Bc4+
```

Comment: I see, so it's about moving the f-pawn causing the black king to be more exposed.

Comment: You mean "black king", of course, and if you insist on f6, try playing the gambit 3...Nc6 (I still don't recommend, but in blitz everything goes :-)

Comment: More reasonably black can play 3... Qe7, which might even recover the pawn.

Comment: Not sure how "reasonable" it is to render your entire Kingside set of pieces immobile; the fact that's pretty much the safest way way to keep from losing a pawn seems to highlight just how bad an idea ...f6 is. Black now can only develop one piece without making multiple moves, White can develop *any* piece except the Rooks with a single move. So Black's best case is they keep the pawn at the cost of 2-3 extra developing moves. As White, I'll take that bargain every time.

Comment: It's certainly not a good line, but better than losing a full rook.